# Connectedness of balls in a compact, connected metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact, connected metric space. For every $\epsilon>0$ define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x\sim_{\epsilon}y$ if and only if there exists a finite sequence $(x=x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n=y)$ such that $d(x_i,x_{i+1})<\epsilon$.

Note that the space is connected if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, the $\epsilon$-equivalence class of every point is the whole space. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/784349/209350). My interest in this collection of equivalence relations is their properties when one restrict them to certain subsets of the space: For a set $A \subset X$ and $\epsilon>0$, define $a \sim_{\epsilon}^{A} b$ if and only if there exists a $\epsilon$-step sequence between $a$ and $b$ contained in $A$.

The following property is something intuitive one could expect to hold in any compact, connected metric space:

> Let $U$ and $V$ be open disjoint subsets of $X$ and denote $K:=(U \cup V)^\complement$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ with $u\sim_{\epsilon}^{U \cup V} v$ through a finite sequence $S_{\epsilon}(u,v) = (u=x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n=v) \subset U \cup V$. Then there exists some $w \in S_{\epsilon}(u,v)$ with $d(w,K)<\epsilon$.

The proof I managed to find consists on the additional assumption that every ball is a connected subset of the space. Assuming this, one can easily see that there exists some ball $B$ of radius $\epsilon$ intersecting $U$ and $V$, so assuming the ball is connected the proof is almost immediate.

I couldn't find a counterexample to this property for compact, connected metric spaces that contain some disconnected ball. Yet, I couldn't prove it when I removed the assumption.

Comment: I can find some $w$ and $w'$ in $\bar U\cap \bar V$ such that $\forall e>0\,(w\sim_e u \land w'\sim_e v)$ but I have not shown that $w$ could equal $w'$.... (Note that $\bar U\cap \bar V$ is disjoint from $U\cup V$ .)

Comment: I believe I do not understand the property you are considering correctly. If I take any $w \in (U \cup V)^c$ then, since $X$ is connected, I have $u \sim_\varepsilon w$ and $w \sim_\varepsilon v$ for every $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ without any condition on $u$ and $v$. What am I missing?

Comment: You are definitely right, I should rewrite it as follows: There can be found w such that its distance from the given sequence inside U\capV is at most epsilon.

Comment: Edit your question again: The highlighted sentence is currently meaningless.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right question? The point  plays essentially no role. As it stands, your question has easy positive answer. (Just take any $w$ on the boundary of the connected component of $U$ containing $u$.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan, it was simply not a precise description and I'm sorry for this and for the bothering. I edited it *again* and I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Taking literally, the new question again has negative answer.

Comment: Do you mean that such $w$ may not exist? I can't find a counterexample to that. Can you explain more?

Comment: Your question went through 10 edits and is still incorrectly formulated. I suggest, you ask a brand new question, just about sequences in compact metric spaces (with the title something like "Connectedness of limit sets of sequences", as the problem has nothing to do with connectedness of metric balls). But make sure that you include all the quantifiers and either a reference to the notion of the limit set of a sequence (say, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) or the precise definition (again with all the quantifiers).

Comment: Lastly: every compact metric space $M$ embeds isometrically in a compact convex subset $C$ of a Banach space. Metric balls in $C$ are, of course, connected.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the unit circle $S^1$ with its standard angular distance function $d$. For non-antipodal points $p, q\in S^1$ let 
$pq$ the closed arc with the end-points $p, q\in S^1$ and of the length $<\pi$. Now, for $\epsilon$ satisfying $0<\epsilon<\pi/2$, let $uv, ab$ be two such arcs of the lengths $\epsilon/2$ and $\epsilon/4$ respectively such that $ab$ is contained in the interior of $uv$. Let $X$ denote the metric space obtained by removing the arc $ab$ from $S^1$ (and keeping the distance function). Then $X$ is clearly connected. Let $k\in S^1$ be the point antipodal to the midpoint of the arc $ab$. Let $U, V$ denote the connected components of $X -\{k\}$ containing $u, v$ respectively. Thus, $K=\{k\}$ is the complement to $U\cup V$ in $X$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$, while $U, V$ are both open in $X$. At the same time, $d(u,k)\ge \pi- \epsilon > \epsilon$ and the same for $v$. Thus, $K$ contains no points within distance $\epsilon$ from the $\epsilon$-chain $\{u, v\}$.

I strongly suspect that you have in mind a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. Maybe I'm missing something basic, but it seems to me that removing the closed arc $ab$ from $S^1$ makes $X$ not compact.

Comment: As for the last comment in your answer, maybe I should mention my motivation. I basically want to prove the following: Let $x_n$ be a sequence in a compact, connected metric space, with the property $d(x_n,x_{n+1})$ converges to $0$. Then the partial limits set of $x_n$ is a connected set. It is quite simple to prove it using the property mentioned in my question.

Comment: @NAR: Just remove the open arc $ab$ instead.

Comment: Sure, thanks. It indeed works, but the property still holds for every $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, so it is not a "full" counterexample to me.

Comment: @NAR: I suggest you think more about your question and about all the quantifiers missing there. In your question you said is "let $\epsilon$". I interpreted this as asking for the property to hold for all $\epsilon>0$, so a counter-example would mean to find **some** $\epsilon>0$. This is what I found.  Needless to say, I still do not know what your question really is.